# Couchbase Lite - use coalesce / ifNullOrMissing in order by clause

Tags: java, couchbase-lite

I have documents stored in a **couchbase lite** database. I use the [query builder](https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/current/java/querybuilder.html) to request these documents in **Java**.

I would like to to order the retrieved documents given two properties: **if one is missing, I'd like to use the value of another** for the ordering.

For example, considering these data stored in the couchbase lite:

```json
{
    "firstname":"Russell",
    "lastname":"Macdonald"
},
{
    "firstname":"Brielle"
    "birthname":"Vaughn"
    "lastname":"Bates"
},
{
    "firstname":"Molly"
    "birthname":"Arellano"
    "lastname":"Nichols"
}
```

I would like to order by birthname. But if the birthname is missing, the lastname should be used instead. The resulting order would be:

- Molly **Arellano** (married Nichols)
- Russell **Macdonald**
- Brielle **Vaughn** (married Bates)

I tried passing the two successive properties to the order by clause. But, unsurprisingly, it did not work:

```java
List<Result> results = select(all())
    .from(database(myDatabase))
    .orderBy(Ordering.property("birthname"), Ordering.property("lastname"))
    .execute().allResults()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with the QueryBuilder interface.  SQL+, however, has a function: "IFMISSINGORNULL(arg1, arg2)" whose value is its first argument, if ISMISSINGORNULL is false for that argument and its second argument otherwise.  You should be able to use the query:

"select * from _ order by IFMISSINGORNULL(birthname, lastname)"

FWIW, the ResultSet produced by Query.execute() should be closed.  It is `AutoClosable` so you might do something like this:

```
final Query query = db.createQuery("select * from _ order by IFMISSINGORNULL(birthname, lastname)");
try (ResultSet results = query.execute()) {
    // parse the results...
}
```